# Show the upper bound of cardinality of $A$ is $C\sqrt{n\log{n}}$

Tags: number-theory

$\forall l,m,n\in \Bbb{Z_+}$, let $A:=\{k: m+1\leq k\leq m+n\text{ and }l-k^2\text{ is a square number}\}$.

Please prove that the number of elements in $A$ is not more than $C\sqrt{n\log n}$, where $C$ is a positive constant that is independent of $l,m$ and $n$.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? If you share with us, it will be easier to give an answer.

Comment: Where did you see this problem? What results do have at your disposal? What are your own thoughts? Giving details as such add context to the question. Many users here feel that having context is a must, and lack thereof is more or less a guaranteed way of attracting negative attention.

Comment: wonder about those who hold the questions with a nice answers just because they can't dig enough or even take a rest, Also I advise everybody thinking that he may have a good question or good answer to avoid this site, make at another site where they respect your specialities (no one can alter, edit, hold, delete your content whatever you may be writing), then you may use this site as a second hand for more outcome

Answer (score 2):

COMMENT.- This is not a problem for everybody. In particular $A\ne\emptyset\iff l$ has not a prime factor of the form $4n+3$ with an odd exponent in its prime decomposition. For example, if $l=7N$ with $7\not|\space N$ then $A=\emptyset$.

The problem reduces to know the number of representations of $l$ as a sum of two squares, $l =k^2+r^2$ with $k\in A$ but considering $0$ and negative integers. In the wonderful Wolphram Language you can put **SquaresR$[2,l]$** and you get this searched number for $l$; for instance if you put SquaresR[2,61], you get the answer $8$ but you must consider atside,for example, of $61=5^2+6^2$, also $61=(-5)^2+6^2$ and others. The given bound $C\sqrt{n\log n}$ is obtained with all these sums involved and the procedure for this is not so "elementary".